# Javascript detect scrollbar in textarea

Tags: javascript, mootools, textarea, scrollbar

I was wondering if anybody knows how I would go about detecting when the scrollbar appears inside a `textarea`.

I am currently using mootools for my JavaScript and I am having issues getting it to detect a scrollbar.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to detect it?

Comment: because I wanted to use it to detect when 3 lines of text had been placed in a textbox and stop allowing any more characters being entered.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
function has_scrollbar(elem_id)
{
    const elem = document.getElementById(elem_id);
    if (elem.clientHeight < elem.scrollHeight)
        alert("The element has a vertical scrollbar!");
    else
        alert("The element doesn't have a vertical scrollbar.");
}
```

See this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qKNXH/

Comment: Since this is a very old question I've edited this answer to add a fiddle forked off @Castrohenge 's code.

Comment: This even works if you have "overflow-y: scroll" on the textarea!  Very nice.

Answer (score 7):

I made a jQuery "compatible" version of [Tommaso Taruffis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3238543/22470) code

```
function resize_until_scrollbar_is_gone(selector) { 
    $.each($(selector), function(i, elem) {
        while (elem.clientHeight < elem.scrollHeight) {
            $(elem).height($(elem).height()+5);
        }
    });
}
```

It can handle multiple elements and accepts: selectors, jQuery objects, or DOM elements.

It can be called like this:

```
resize_until_scrollbar_is_gone('textarea');
```

Answer (score 5):

Tommaso's solution works perfectly, even with a text area. But if the user were to type in the textarea and suddenly the textarea gave itself a scrollbar, your javascript wouldn't know or be triggered.So you might want to add something like

```
 onKeyUp='has_scrollbar("textareaID")'
```

Answer (score -1):

For React I've found https://github.com/andreypopp/react-textarea-autosize

```
import Textarea from 'react-textarea-autosize';
...

<Textarea maxRows={3} />
```