# How to give absolute content boundaries to a textarea in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a `textarea` to emulate a piece of 9.5x11 Letter sized US paper.

I have a `textarea` that is appropriately scaled to the 9.5x11 size; however, I want to prevent users from being able to add more text that would overflow the `textarea`.

The goal is to limit the user to the boundaries of the `textarea`, and thus preserve the ability to scale the content to Letter sized paper.

I've tried using `resize:none`, and each option for `overflow`, but these mainly seem to deal with the pixel size of the `textarea`, and not the content inside it. How can I use Javascript, CSS, or HTML to keep the user within the boundaries of the `textarea`?

Comment: You might find this interesting - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042115/javascript-detect-textarea-to-be-full - not sure if this is a duplicate of your question as you are asking about fixing boundaries.

Comment: If you know the character count perhaps this post will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414420/how-to-prevent-user-to-enter-text-in-textarea-after-reaching-max-character-limit

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I think that the concept is interesting, and if other solutions don't come up I will look into trying to use this method. I was looking for a method that would provide more of a "hard block" effect that prevented the user from typing the characters over the limit, I dislike the effect of using javascript to delete the users' words in front of them.

Comment: I suppose **maxlength** will do

Comment: @BenHare The interesting thing about this project is that I'm working with a customized WYSIWYG editor, so the textarea will contain images and large text, I am looking to create hard boundaries around the text area in order to account for the possible irregularities. A character limit would apply differently in each case and allow users who use large text to overflow beyond the 9.5x11 limits.

Comment: How, exactly, are you making the size of the box 9.5x11? THAT is what I'm wondering about.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie The textarea just needs to maintain the 9.5x11 ratio, the text size is variable. So it's done with simple max-height and max-width variables that follow the ratio.

Comment: Normally I would say something as simple as `<textarea style="resize:none;" wrap="hard" maxlength="250"></textarea>` where the styling prevents the resize, the wrap attribute prevents text from overflowing on the side and the maxlength attribute sets the maximum amount of characters a user can type. But since this is a WYSIWYG editor, the max amount of characters that fit the available space varies.

Comment: My best solution so far would be to create a custom javascript event that fires on the textarea overflow event and blocks any further additions to the area. Just have to think about how to code it.

Comment: Can you include `html`, `css` at Question?

Comment: I didn't want to turn this into an answer just yet as it still has a few drawbacks to it, but it should get you pretty close: https://jsfiddle.net/2dmp57tp/

Comment: Fixed one of the problems to improve it a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/2dmp57tp/2/