# I want to know if the user moved to a new line Without pressing the enter button in textarea element

Tags: javascript, textarea

When the user writes anything in a textarea, and when pressing the enter button to moving to a new line, there is a character created `'\n'`.

What about if the user continued to write until he got to the end of the line, and then turn in to a new line automatically without pressing the enter button, in this case how can I to know this ?

The following code Will increase the textarea when press the enter button, and I want to doing the same behavior when automatically turn in to a new line without press the enter button:

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById('text');
textarea.onkeyup = function (eve) {
    if (eve.keyCode == 13) { // 13 = enter key
        textarea.style.height = textarea.offsetHeight + 25 + 'px';
    }
};
```

```css
#text {width:300px;}
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: You can figure out how many characters are in a line then `onchange` event check the number of characters in the textarea then divide by the number of characters in a line to see how many lines there are...

Comment: [What if you check for scrollbars?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3238515/1267304)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple libraries that can do this for you. E.g.

http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

https://alexdunphy.github.io/flexText/

**Edit:**

As you didn't want to use the library directly, I checked [the code of the jacklmoores autosize](https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize/blob/master/src/autosize.js).

What it does is basically that it sets the height to auto and then uses the scroll height as the height for the textarea. I also changed your onkeyup to onkeydown as to let it resize when holding a key.

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('text');
textarea.onkeydown = function (eve) {
    textarea.style.height = 'auto'
    textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight+'px';
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p575mnsu/5/)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know the idea.

Comment: I edited the answer with the gist of how jacklmoores library works

Answer (score -1):

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById('text');
textarea.onkeyup = function (eve) {
    if (eve.keyCode == 13) { // 13 = enter key
        textarea.style.height = textarea.offsetHeight + 25 + 'px';
    }
};
```

```css
#text {width:300px;}
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: This detects if the enter key has been pressed. This is not what the OP is asking.