# How can I limit the characters in textarea by textarea's size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## What I have:

I have a textarea with a dynamic width and height. I'm using p5.dom.js to create DOM elements with width and height according to the windows width and height.

## What I want:

I want to restrict the characters in the textarea so it can't be bigger than the size of the textarea. When the character get to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE0rH.png) point, the user shouldn't be able to insert more characters.

## Problems:

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Even when I remove the resize and the scroll bar, it doesn't stop it from going down. When the user types one more letter [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulHNo.png) happens.

I know that I can use `maxlength` or rows and cols, but because the textarea have a dynamic width and height, I'm trying to find a solution where you don't use this attributes.

## Solutions:

1. The only solution the I thought of this making a event to check when the scroll bar goes down and remove 1 character until the scroll bar goes back to the top. How to check that?
2. Removing the ability of the scroll and not just hiding the scroll bar. I look in a lot of places but i could only find questions that hide the scroll bar.

If there's no way to do that in CSS, jQuery would be a good way.

## Edit 1:

It's ok if some users have lower character limit than others

Comment: I am not sure if there's a way to do it even in JavaScript. The maximum you could restrict the user is to use the right number of characters.

Comment: For accessibility reasons users may have increased the default font size. This might mean some users will have a lower limit than others.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman and do you know a way to decrese the font so when the scroll goes down, you cant still see all the text in the textarea ?

Comment: @Vencovsky That might be possible. But how do you gauge the user's font size? Some people might have bigger fonts, a different OS, where the fonts appear in a different size. So it's kinda tricky to understand how HTML renders in those cases. I have come across a lot of issues like this, but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: @Vencovsky In simple sense, you won't be able to detect the scroll bar coming and going out of textarea - or wait, guess that's possible.

Comment: as @PraveenKumarPurushothaman touched on, looking for when the scrollbar is added into the textbox, and then construct some logic around that would probably be a way of doing it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238515/javascript-detect-scrollbar-in-textarea

Comment: Thanks @Martin and that's a perfect dupe.

Comment: Simply removing one character from the end is not really the proper solution - I might have added more than one character at a time, for example via copy&paste. Ok, you could keep removing characters from the end, until it fits again - but what if I moved my text cursor? I have typed a wonderful, prosaic text that the great writers of history would envy me for, then I go back to the beginning of the text, copy&paste something into there - and you start cutting off my wonderful work at the end? Oh man, am I going to be pissed at the !%&$ that treats my creative input that way :-)

Comment: it might be wrong, but I will try to share my idea: basically you could calculate the "maximum" amount of character into a determined height: eg. 200px - 300 character, 250px - 350 character and so on, then create an if else function according width that. (it might not be the best way though)