# CSS check if textarea has scrollbar

Tags: css

Is there any way in CSS to detect if a textarea has a scrollbar (vertical or otherwise) ?

```
textarea:has(:scrollbar-shown)
```

I am checking for latest modern browser versions only.

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238515/javascript-detect-scrollbar-in-textarea

Comment: But I am not looking for a JavaScript solution - even if its an upcoming CSS4 feature also helps - atleast I'll know that it's in the works. Or will this never happen ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript to do that,

```
    const textArea = document.querySelector("textarea");
    if (textArea.clientHeight < textArea.scrollHeight){
        console.log("The element has a vertical scrollbar!")}

    else {
        console.log("The element doesn't have a vertical scrollbar.")}
```

Comment: He asked for a CSS solution, not javascript. Please delete this.